# Ideas on triggering an update on my database when hosted on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm not entirely sure on how to implement this so I was wondering what the best way to do it would be.

Here is the scenario:

I'm hosting a website on windows azure. To put it simply the website allows users to post ads. The ads are supposed to expire after 30 days. The status of the ad is regulated by a status column in the database. So if I set the status to 'E' the add will not show up anymore.

My current solution is to query the database and check for expired ads by putting this logic in the session_start method. I don't believe this is the best way of solving this problem. I've noticed that it sometimes takes awhile for the homepage to load when accessing the site and I'm blaming this implementation.

I was curious if there are better solutions out there. I was imagining a constant polling of the database to update the statuses if necessary but I'm not sure where to start when the website is hosted on azure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the Preview version of [Windows Azure Scheduler](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/scheduler/), to quote:

> Run jobs on simple or complex recurring schedules
>
> Windows Azure Scheduler allows you to invoke actions - such as calling
>   HTTP/S endpoints or posting a message to a storage queue - on any
>   schedule. With Scheduler, you create jobs in the cloud that reliably
>   call services inside and outside of Windows Azure. You choose whether
>   to run those jobs right away, on a recurring schedule, or at some
>   point in the future

Another option is to use a free service like [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) to hit an endpoint (such as a webpage) that triggers your job that updates the ads.

Comment: I will check out the scheduler. Thanks for the response!